# Check all or uncheck all in multi checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code for multi check-box

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset data-role="collapsible">
    <legend>Pick one</legend>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="ZIBI" align="right" >
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
myArray1 = new Array(
           "1","2","3","4","5","6"
           );

 $("#ZIBI").html('');
           for (var i = 0; i < myArray1.length; i++) {
               row = myArray1[i];
               $("#ZIBI").append(
                   '<label for=' + row + '>' + row + '</label>' +
                   '<input type="checkbox" name="favcolor" id=' + row + ' value=' + row + '>');
           }
           $('#ZIBI').trigger('create');
```

how to check all or uncheck all by pressing any button ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

New elements should be added to `$(".selector").controlgroup("container")` not `$(".selector")` directly. If you add them to main div, elements won't be styled as a _controlgroup`.

---

You need to *refresh* `.checkboxradio("refresh")` checkbox or radio to apply jQM styles. Another point, `.trigger("create")` is deprecated as of jQM 1.4 and replaced with `.enhanceWithin()`.

```
myArray1 = new Array(
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
/* remove previous elements */
$("#ZIBI").controlgroup("container").html('');

for (var i = 0; i < myArray1.length; i++) {
    row = myArray1[i];
    /* add new ones to container */
    $("#ZIBI").controlgroup("container").append(
        '<label for=' + row + '>' + row + '</label>' +
        '<input type="checkbox" name="favcolor" id=' + row + ' value=' + row + '>');
}
/* refresh controlgroup and enhance elements within */
$("#ZIBI").controlgroup().enhanceWithin();

/* check/uncheck on button click */
$("#foo").on("click", function () {
    var status = $("#ZIBI [type=checkbox]").eq(0).prop("checked") ? false : true;
    $("#ZIBI [type=checkbox]").prop("checked", status).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6mvgrdvz/)**

Answer (score 1):

In this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6ecyo1ct/) you'll find a method to check/uncheck all checkboxes within a given div, using a checkbox with id `_main`:

```
function checkAll(e){
    e = e || event;
    var from = e.target || e.srcElement
       ,cbs = this.querySelectorAll('input'), i=1;
    if (/^_main$/i.test(from.id)){
        for (;i<cbs.length;i+=1){
            cbs[i].checked = from.checked; 
        }
    } else {
      var main = document.querySelector('#_main')
         ,j = cbs.length;    
      for (;i<cbs.length;i+=1){
          j -= cbs[i].checked ? 0 : 1;
      }
      main.checked = j === cbs.length ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried to adapt your code to my code - did not succeed, can i get some help ? I'm pretty new ..... :)

Comment: Hi @SoftIT, here's a jsfiddle containing your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6ecyo1ct/. The link in the answer also points to it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset data-role="collapsible">
    <legend>Pick one</legend>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="ZIBI" align="right" >
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" id="all" value="Toggle" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#all').on('click', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#ZIBI').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true); 
    } else {
        $('#ZIBI').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false); 
    }
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/rxvojpdu/).